# Mysql map column name based on condition

Tags: mysql

In my current project, I have a MySQL table (temp_data) with the following fields:

- device_id VARCHAR (32)
- event_layer TINYINT (4)

It has the following sample data:

[image]

**What I am trying to achieve is:** When I execute `select * from temp_data` (at the moment it returns the above output) then for `event_layer` = 2, I would like to have `device_id` column name to `instance_id` and for other event_layer values i.e. `event_layer` != 2 the `device_id` column name remains as it is.

I tried to use this query:

```
select device_id, event_layer 
from temp_data 
where event_layer != 2 
union all 
select device_id as instance_id, event_layer 
from temp_data 
where event_layer = 2
```

but it didn't work.

**[Updated]**

The expected output is as follow (output in JSON format):

```
[{"device_id" : "a2222222","event_layer":4},
 {"device_id" : "a3333333","event_layer":4},
 {"device_id" : "010146af2519a7a2","event_layer":4},
 {"instance_id" : "ABC9998765","event_layer":2},
 {"instance_id" : "ABC9998765","event_layer":2},
 {"instance_id" : "ABC9998765","event_layer":2}]
```

For all `event_layer = 2` records, the `device_id` field should rename to `instance_id`.

Any efficient way to achieve this (should I create a view to achieve the desired result)? Please share your views.

Comment: A column has only 1 name. What is your expected output?

Comment: You want to have multiple column names? There is just one column name....you can construct this select with 3 columns with values based on event_layer if you want

Comment: @forpas: Added the expected output.

Comment: *The expected output is as follow (output in JSON format):* Do you want MySQL to return this JSON?

Comment: @Akina: Yes bcoz if we look at MySQL output in tabular format then I have `NULL` values as mentioned in Soheil Rahsaz answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(CASE event_layer WHEN 2 THEN 'instance_id'
                                                         ELSE 'device_id'
                                                         END,
                                 device_id,
                                 'event_layer',
                                 event_layer)) output
FROM temp_data;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99576c449e3affbd3baf0b54f3fbc8d0

Answer (score 1):

Once you specify an alias for a column, it will be used for all unions. By selecting an extra column and `NULL` as its value you can achieve this.

```
SELECT NULL AS instance_id, device_id, event_layer
FROM temp_data
WHERE event_layer != 2

UNION ALL

SELECT device_id, NULL, event_layer
FROM temp_data
WHERE event_layer = 2
```

But of course, you will have `NULL` values for `instance_id` and `device_id`. You can avoid them in your server-side code

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to get output in JSON format so that I don't have `NULL` values?

Comment: look at @Akina's answer.